Retention label policy limits in Microsoft 365
I've read and re-read the limits and cannot get my head around some of the details.
The documentation states:
there are also some limits on the maximum number of policies for retention per workload:
SharePoint or OneDrive: (all sites automatically included): 13
SharePoint or OneDrive (specific locations included or excluded): 2,600

and also
If you use static scopes and the optional configuration to include or exclude specific users, specific Microsoft 365 groups, or specific sites, there are some limits per policy to be aware of.
Maximum numbers of items per policy for retention for static scopes:

Exchange mailboxes: 1,000
Microsoft 365 Groups: 1,000
Teams channel messages: 1,000
Teams chats and Copilot interactions messages: 1,000
Viva Engage community messages: 1,000
Viva Engage user messages: 1,000
SharePoint sites: 100
OneDrive accounts: 100

What I understand:

Whenever a policy is created that includes all SharePoint sites (communication sites or M365 group sites), it can include all sites in the tenant (no matter how many sites) but we can only create 13 of these
If a static scope is used that is configured with include/exclude lists, it can have no more than 100 sites / 1000 M365 group sites specified in those lists and we can have 2600 of these

What is not clear:
Assuming that I have retention label policies using static scopes applied to All SharePoint sites AND All M365 group sites (so, no specification), which is the limit that I'm bound to, if any? (in particular, for M365 group sites)
It seems like it could be 1000 M365 group sites per policy (judging by static scope limits), but it could also be 13 policies (since we don't include/exclude sites AND based on general SharePoint workload limits), or it could even be no limit at least for M365 group sites since these are not specified in global workload and usually not considered "SharePoint sites".
In other words, how many policies can I have that include all M365 group sites?

